# SQL Function calls ignored with "HAVING" clause

Tags: mysql, sql

For the below query, the MAX function seems to be completely ignored. The MAX function has no effect on the result of the query

```
SELECT alarm_severity_id
FROM alarm_notification
WHERE alarm_life_cycle_id = 25
having MAX(event_timestamp);
```

Comment: ORDER BY event_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;  ??

Comment: `having MAX(event_timestamp);` does not make any sense and is essentially invalid SQL. Any other DBMS would simply reject that statement with a syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT alarm_severity_id
FROM alarm_notification
WHERE alarm_life_cycle_id = 25
HAVING MAX(event_timestamp);
```

Your `HAVING` clause is saying:  take the maximum of the timestamp.  If the maximum is not equal to zero or NULL, then everything is fine.  This is exactly equivalent:

```
HAVING MAX(event_timestamp) <> 0
```

I suspect you want:

```
SELECT alarm_severity_id
FROM alarm_notification
WHERE alarm_life_cycle_id = 25
ORDER BY event_timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

EDIT:

To optimize performance, create an index on `alarm_life_cycle_id` and `event_timestamp`:

```
create index alarm_notification_alci_et on alarm_notification(alarm_life_cycle_id, event_timestamp)
```

Comment: Thnx for the answer Gordon. I get your point. Infact the query that you posted was the one I used earlier. But the number of records in notification table can be huge (can range from 1 to millions). With the above query, would that not have a impact on the performance? Is there any alternate way?

Comment: You should have an index on `event_timestamp` and have a look at [how MySQL is optimizing LIMIT queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html).

Answer (score 3):

1. There should be correct condition like `having MAX(event_timestamp) > 100`
2. There should be `group by` if you use `MAX`
3. Or do as @Gordon Linoff said (with `order by` + `limit 1`).

Comment: You do not need a `group by` to use aggregation functions.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff you're right, `group by` is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is incomplete, you need to use an operator and a value with the "having" statement, like

```
HAVING MAX(event_timestamp) = 100
```

What exactly are you trying to do?