# Creating Index for a table that had existed for a long time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has millions of records. I was writing some new queries on the same table. While writing one of the queries, I realised that to improve the performance, I need to create a index on a column of the table.

My question is, if new index is created now, will it improve my performance right away? My understanding of indexes is that during data insertion, indexes helps sort the data. So if there is already loads of data in the table, will that data be not indexed and only new data will be indexed?

Comment: you need to provide the existing table structure and the query you want to execute. Just by adding indexes will not improve the performance and it depends on the query you are executing.

Comment: Abhik, Please refer to the discussion on [STACK-OVERFLOW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611459/sql-function-calls-ignored-with-having-clause/23611545?noredirect=1#23611545), on the need to create a index. The query is also mentioned in the discussion.

Comment: No, all existing rows will be indexed during the index creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chance it will be immediate, but once statistics is updated, it will give you even better performance in all likelihood (if it is a good/appropriate index).  You can run it manually to better optimize:

```
 UPDATE STATISTICS <table>.<column> ESTIMATE SAMPLE 20 PERCENT
```

Comment: There is also mention of using "ANALYZE TABLE" to get the engine to optimize it's paths.